# Implementing Web Services with spring without using spring-remoting-2.0.8.jar as this jar is not released by spring community

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-remoting

We are trying to implement Web Services with spring and axis.
As a reference we used [THIS SITE](https://skysoftarchive.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/implementing-web-services-with-spring-and-axis/).Here they have suggested to implement end point by extending ServletEndpointSupport as below

```
import org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport;

public class SpringWSEndPoint extends ServletEndpointSupport
{
}
```

But the class **org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport** is from the JAR **spring-remoting-2.0.8.jar** which is not released by spring frame work in latest release.
we know that **spring-remoting**  became a part of **spring-context**, so newer versions are released with spring-context.

My question is 
**How can we implement the same using Spring-context jar ?** 
**What is equivalent class of ServletEndpointSupport in Spring-context jar?**

Immediate help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using **Spring-WS** - especially since ServletEndpointSupport was deprecated - http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/remoting/78249-deprecation-of-servletendpointsupport

You can explore spring-ws: http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/

Converting these to RESTful services isn't too complicated either.